# Testing Paypal Express Integration / Sandbox Credentials / I am not a programmer

Tags: paypal, integration, sandbox, credentials

I have zero programming skills / knowledge and am trying to integrate paypal express into my shopping cart by following instructions but I don't know what I'm doing and don't understand a lot of it. I would love some help if someone can help me out.

I have created a developer account and gotten the user and password and API certificate and inserted them into my cart settings.
I read on the cart integration instructions I need sandbox credentials to test the integration with a dummy purchase.

So I eventually find some very rough instructions on paypal developer which I dont fully understand, you have to create an app to get tehse credentials? I dont even know what an app is, what its for but I create one somehow, but I dont see any sandbox credentials anywhere, when i look in my manage apps page I see this thing I have created and "sandbox ID" and "Live ID" codes next to them. I am not sure what they are and how I use them, are these credentials?

In paypal developer instructions for the credentials I see it says to go to the paypal account the money will be deposited in, "Get your test credentials by navigating to the Profile > API credentials tab of the Business account you want to use in your request:" but when I go to my paypal account I cannot find this. I do not have a business account (premier) but I was under the impression you didnt have to have a business account to integrate paypal express checkout, you had a choice with either premier or business. Do I need to upgrade to business absolutely? Is this where I find these credentials? Am I barking up the wrong tree with the application stuff? Let's say I finally get these holy grail credentials to test the integration, what do I do with them? I have no idea. I am very sorry for my total lack of knowledge and understanding and thank oyu to anyone willing to help me out.

I am trying to integrate the checkout with Viart shopping cart. Thank you.

Comment: If you have zero programming skills then you're in the wrong place. This is not a general computer help site, it's a Q&A resource for specific questions about programming that can have definite answers. Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page to get a better understanding of the site's format.

Comment: I'm sorry but I had nowhere else to go and this is where I was directed by paypal developer

Comment: Andrew has helped me in my query so I have found it has been of help to me in "help" capacity where there is nowhere else to ask Adi

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an App for Express Checkout.  That is only for Adaptive Payments, and Express is not part of that.  All you need are the API credentials.

The easiest to get those credentials is to [use this tool](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run).  Sign in to that with your PayPal account and it will return your username, password, and signature.

Assuming that Viart has PayPal Express Checkout integrated already, then you'll have somewhere in your control panel where you can enable it as a payment gateway on your site, and then within the settings of that somewhere it would be asking you for those credentials.  Once you fill those in correctly and enable Express Checkout, it should show up and function for you in whatever way Viart has implemented it.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help Andrew, you've been fantastic. It's nice to know that I don't need an app. I have filled in the settings with the certificate rather than the signature, so that part is done.

Comment: Sorry, enter does not go to the next line... anyway, I was trying to do the testing but you're right it should function if I fill in the credentials so I will ask viart if they can test it for me, this is too much for me when all I want to do is get the shop up and running. Once again, thank you so much for simplifying things and explaining them to me, you've been a big help. Cheers.